# GeoCode - get coordinates of the polygon for a selected building

Tags: geolocation

I am trying to retrieve the polygon coordinates for the selected building on the map.
e.g. we have a building e.g.

https://maps.google.com.au/maps?oe=utf-8&client=firefox-a&q=49+STAFFORD+ST+ABBOTSFORD&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x6ad64303493368df:0xfb752bd3456411,49+Stafford+St,+Abbotsford+VIC+3067&gl=au&ei=CWo4UJfgBMWjiQeZ2oDADQ&ved=0CCIQ8gEwAA

49+Stafford+St,+Abbotsford+VIC+3067 AUSTRALIA.

in the following format

POLYGON ((144.994479667 -37.80101375, 144.9946515 -37.80103, 144.994690608 -37.800771417, 144.99451885 -37.8007547, 144.994479667 -37.80101375))

This will help me to draw the polygon and shade the selected building.

What is the best way to retreive this data from the API? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: YES it is doable
NO it's not free.

The approx price for this cadstral database in Australia is $40,000 per two years.

**update 29may 2016**
Australian government has released this database into public. Google GNAF, you would not need to pay $40,000 per annum anymore